# Similar to HashSet in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am java programmer. There is concept of `HashSet` in Java that don't add duplicate elements in a `Set`. What is the similar concept in iPhone that do same ?

Please hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most collection classes of the Foundation framework are described in detail in the ["Collections Programming Topics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html) documentation. If order is relevant then you can use NS(Mutable)OrderedSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSSet in iOS. NSSet is a (unordered) collection of unique items. So, you can find the unique items in your array like so:

```
     NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];

    // iterate over the unique items
    for(id element in uniqueElements)
       {
          // do something
       }
```

NSSet most likely uses a hash algorithm to make insertion O(1) (compared to O(n^2) to check if each item is unique by iteration), but the Apple documentation does not make such a guarantee so you probably shouldn't count on that implementation detail.

If, for some reason you need to keep the unique items in a sorted (ordered) collection, you can turn the set back into an array with -[NSSet allObjects] and then sort the resulting array.

Comment: I want they should be in same order as I insert into it. Does NSSet will be helpful for that ?

Comment: If you want it to be in same order then use NSOrderedSet: It is the ordered collection of distinct objects.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) use the has of `NSObject` to make sure that there are not duplicates.

Or [`NSMutableSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)
 if you need to add thing to the set.

Comment: so I use `NSSet`, will it be helpful to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with java I can't confirm that they are 100% the same. But `NSSet` does doe what you descripted.

Comment: From the documentation it seems that `NSSet` is immutable. That would make it fundamentally different from `HashSet` in Java, and probably wouldn't do what is required.

Comment: That is how Objective-C work, just use `NSMutableSet`.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` is the Java implementation of a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). [`NSHashTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is, I believe, the Cocoa equivalent.